# XPath abs function not working while using in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xpath, xquery

We have a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_s_eval_expr] 
    @formula NVARCHAR(max),
    @result SQL_VARIANT OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) 
    DECLARE @cal_value FLOAT
    
    SET @sql = N'DECLARE @x xml=''''SELECT @cal_value=CAST(@x.query('''+@formula+''') as nvarchar(max))'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@cal_value FLOAT OUTPUT',@cal_value OUTPUT

    SET @result = @cal_value
    SELECT @result
END
GO
```

It is created to evaluate mathematical expressions, I understand that there are better ways to solve the expression, it is deployed in production and I don't have the right to modify it.

It works with most of the functions but is throwing errors while using it to find the absolute value of a number.

For example,

```
DECLARE @formula NVARCHAR(max) = ' abs(-1.5) '
DECLARE @result SQL_VARIANT 
EXEC [usp_s_eval_expr] @formula, @result OUTPUT
SELECT @result
```

This throws the error following error whereas `ceiling` and `round` functions work well.

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_s_eval_expr, Line 32 [Batch Start Line 0]
> XQuery [query()]: There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:abs()'

Is there any way to achieve the absolute value of a number order than checking less than 0, the reason why I don't want to check less than is the expression that results in -1.5 is very big, and I don't want to use it twice to achieve the abs functionality.

Comment: Why are you using "dynamic' SQL here? As far as I can tell both values you pass can be variables/parameters so you are just creating a large security vulnerability here.

Comment: @Larnu I understand the concern here, but the SP is not in my control

Comment: Then feedback to whoever does control it; that procedure is *incredibly* **dangerous**.

Comment: Imagine, for example, if someone passed this value for `@formula`: `<a>1</a>') AS varchar(MAX)); CREATE LOGIN a WITH PASSWORD = 'a', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER a; --`. Depending on the permissions of the account the query is running under, you very well might have a new `sysadmin` account on your instance.

Comment: Sure I will pass the security loophole to the concerned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation available by download from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_standards/MS-SQLSTANDLP/89fb00b1-4b9e-4296-92ce-a2b3f7ca01d2 SQL Server does not support the fn:abs() function.

Also: are you sure about the namespace `{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}`. That's from an early draft of XPath 2.0, not the final W3C spec. But I don't think SQL Server ever implemented the final spec anyway.

Another way to get the absolute value might be to convert to a string and strip the minus sign.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the link, I guess I have to use the option of checking the value less than 0 and multiply it by -1. Regarding the link, that's what I get when I execute in SQL Server 2019 Express edition